# Add closed beta testers programmatically in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

In iOS you can use the iTunes Connect API to add beta testers programmatically as seen here: https://github.com/fastlane/itc-api-docs

Is there a equivalent solution for Google Play Closed Beta/Alpha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not add programmatically alpha/beta tester. However you can upload `.csv`
for that

> Add email addresses separated by commas or click Upload new CSV file.
> If you use a .CSV file, put each email address on its own line without
> any commas. If you upload a .CSV file, it will overwrite any email
> addresses you've added.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: `grammatically`? Maybe you mean `programmatically` :-)